# Why isn't there a remove(int position) method in Android's JSONArray?

Tags: android, json

I started building an Android app that uses a flat file for storage.  The app doesn't store more than six records, and I'm familiar with JSON, so I just write out a `JSONArray` to the file.

I just discovered today, though, that the Android JSON API doesn't include a `remove()` option.  Huh?  Do I have to dump the array into another collection, remove it, then rebuild the `JSONArray`?  What's the point?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions and answers. Complaints regarding the JSON API should be directed to the authors, who are at json.org. Or, since it is open source, you are welcome to actually modify it and use the modified version yourself.

Comment: Actually this is an android SDK problem. Star the issue here to get someone to patch it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53461

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` are meant to (de)serialize data to JSON, not manipulate data. A `remove()` method may seem to make sense, but where's the limit? Would you expect to be able to access attributes on serialized objects? Access or update nested data structures?

The idea is, indeed, that you manipulate data structures "natively".

Comment: This makes sense.  In my case, I have a data store consisting of a plain data object (POJO, Bean, whatever you want to call it) and List.  I should be dealing with these objects directly, then writing out their state via JSON.

Comment: You have a public API, you can't just randomly remove functions from it just because you think your way of coding is better.

Comment: I think the org.json API was made over 15 years ago. Why not allow people to re-order an array of JSONObject that were fetched from the internet? Why is it mandatory to create a List<JSONObject> rather than reordering the JSONArray directly? loops of loops just for doing the same thing.

Comment: @RafaelSanches I completely agree. Languages should strive to be useful, not to introduce meaningless barriers that require extra make-work. Considering the ubiquity of JSON (here in 2020) it's astonishing that this is still a task to be handled manually!

Answer (score 18):

This is useful sometimes in android when you want to use the json structure directly, without looping around to convert. Please use this only when you do things like removing a row on long clicks or something like that. Don't use that inside a loop!

Notice that I only use this when I'm handling JSONObject inside the array.

```
public static JSONArray remove(final int idx, final JSONArray from) {
    final List<JSONObject> objs = asList(from);
    objs.remove(idx);

    final JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    for (final JSONObject obj : objs) {
        ja.put(obj);
    }

    return ja;
}

public static List<JSONObject> asList(final JSONArray ja) {
    final int len = ja.length();
    final ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final JSONObject obj = ja.optJSONObject(i);
        if (obj != null) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I use:

```
public static JSONArray removeFrom(JSONArray jsonArray, int pos){
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            if (i != pos) {
                jsonArray.put(jsonArray.get(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This solution works well for me when you need to remove a row on API < 19

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check it out now. Seems like API 19 from Android (4.4) actually allows this method.

```
Call requires API level 19 (current min is 16): org.json.JSONArray#remove
```

I got that error while trying to use it. Hope it helps you, now that it's there!