# Remove a Jsonobject based on some key-value from JsonArray android

Tags: android

I am working on an android application and somewhere in my application, I want to remove some JsonObject from jsonArray. Below is the JsonArray:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/e0/39/01/137a8_8640.png?c=279d",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/5f/3a/01/13826_c4c9.png?c=ff74",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/ac/39/01/13774_7183.png?c=35ee",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/a7/3a/01/1386e_d5c5.png?c=3f1e",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/1d/3a/01/137e4_e803.png?c=9ab9",
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "image": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/cf/3a/01/13896_edab.png?c=1e7b",

  }
```

]

Now from this JsonArray, I want to remove JsonObject which is having id equals to 2.

How can I do this, I want to optimize this code because, I can do it using a for loop, but I do not want to do it using for loop.
Is there any other way to do it. Please help me if anyone know about this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Which json library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string); 
int len = jsonArray.length();
int position = -1;
int wantedID = 2;
for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.get("id"));
    if (id == wantedID) {
        position = i;
        break;
    }
   }
JSONArray jsonArray_out = jsonArray;
       if (position >= 0) {
//for 19 API use this: jsonArray_out.remove(position);
//or remove using this code:
      jsonArray_out = remove(position, jsonArray);
       }

       String out  = jsonArray_out.toString();
```

Using this methods you can remove data from JSON:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526047/1979882

```
public static JSONArray remove(final int idx, final JSONArray from) {
    final List<JSONObject> objs = asList(from);
    objs.remove(idx);

    final JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    for (final JSONObject obj : objs) {
        ja.put(obj);
    }

    return ja;
}

public static List<JSONObject> asList(final JSONArray ja) {
    final int len = ja.length();
    final ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final JSONObject obj = ja.optJSONObject(i);
        if (obj != null) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

or this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250881/1979882

Comment: remove() requires API level 19.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [JsonArray](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) from Gson library, you can use [remove()](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#remove-int-) method.

For example:

```
int idToRemove = 3;

JsonElement elementToRemove = null;
for(JsonElement e : jsonArray) {
    JsonObject o = e.getAsJsonObject();
    if(o.get("id").getAsInt() == idToRemove) {
        elementToRemove = e;
        break;
    }
}
if (elementToRemove != null) jsonArray.remove(elementToRemove);
```

Alternatively, use `Iterator<JsonElement>` explicitly.