# Remove JSON Object from JSON Array on onClick in Android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and when a user clicks on an item, that item gets selected and its id is saved in a JSON Array. Similarly, if the user selects an item and later decides to unselect it, the item should be removed from the JSON Array and an updated array should be created. I am able to create a JSON Array on onClick but at !onClick I am not able to remove the JSON Object from the JSON Array.

Here is my Adapter Class:

```
public class ClientListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ClientListData> clientListData;
public JSONArray clientArray = new JSONArray();

public ClientListAdapter(List<ClientListData> clientListData, Context context) {
    super();

    this.clientListData = clientListData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ClientListData clientListDataModel = clientListData.get(position);
    holder.clientList.setText(clientListDataModel.getClientName());

    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(clientListDataModel.isSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
    holder.clientList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clientListDataModel.setSelected(!clientListDataModel.isSelected());

            try {
                JSONObject clientObject = new JSONObject();
                if(clientListDataModel.isSelected()) {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    clientObject.put("id", clientListData.get(position).getClientId());
                    clientArray.put(clientObject);
                }

                if(!clientListDataModel.isSelected()) {

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    for(int i=0; i<clientArray.length(); i++) {
                        clientObject = clientArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        clientObject.remove(clientListData.get(position).getClientId());
                        //clientArray.put(clientObject);
                    }
                }
                //clientArray.put(clientObject);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("client id array", ""+clientArray);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return clientListData == null ? 0:clientListData.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView clientList;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        clientList = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_client_list);

    }
}
```

}

and here is my Model Class:

```
public class ClientListData {

private String clientId;
private String clientName;
private boolean isSelected = false;

public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

public String getClientName() {
    return clientName;
}

public void setClientName(String clientName) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}
```

}

Note that I have created a boolean variable in the Model Class to listen to onClicks.

**Note:-** since I am using org.json, I am not able to use the remove method on JSON Array, after a lot of search I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639031/why-isnt-there-a-removeint-position-method-in-androids-jsonarray) question.

Comment: does not `JSONArray#remove(int index)` work?

Comment: Instead of JSONArray use ArrayList and convert it into JSONArray at sending time

Comment: @pskink I have not tried that, give me a moment, But my requirement is to remove a specific id from the Array which I am doing through clientObject.remove(clientListData.get(position).getClientId());

Comment: @JRamesh could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:[**UPDATE**]

```
if (!clientListDataModel.isSelected()) {

            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            for (int i = 0; i < clientArray.length(); i++) {
                clientObject = clientArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if (clientObject.getString("id").equals(clientListDataModel.getClientId())) {
                    clientArray=removeFromJsonArray(clientArray,i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

removeFromJsonArray function:

```
private JSONArray removeFromJsonArray(JSONArray array,int position){
 if(array==null)return null;
 JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
            for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                //Excluding the item at position
                if (i != position)
                {
                    newArray.put(jsonArray.get(i));
                }
            }
       return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your method but I get error at clientArray.remove(i), I guess the remove method is not supported by org.json

Comment: Let me try the removeFromJsonArray function, I have updated the question as well.

Comment: The position is the index of that clientObject found in the clientArray. Id has nothing to do with the position of the object in the array

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Antonis Lat, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add This code in activity


    private ArrayList<Integer> selectedIdList = new ArrayList<>();


    ClientListAdapter  adapter=new ClientListAdapter (list,this,new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
                if(list.size()>position){
                 ClientListDataModel clientListDataModel=list.get(position);
    if clientListDataModel!= null) {
                clientListDataModel.setSelected(!clientListDataModel.isSelected());

                        boolean isSelected = clientListDataModel.isSelected();
                        if (!isSelected) {
                            if (selectedIdList.contains(clientListDataModel.getId())) {
                                int index = selectedIdList.indexOf(clientListDataModel.getId());
                                selectedIdList.remove(index);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (!selectedIdList.contains(clientListDataModel.getId())) {
                                selectedIdList.add(clientListDataModel.getId());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }
        });


    And at sending time 



        public JSONArray clientArray = new JSONArray();
        if(!selectedIdList.empty()){
            for(int i=0; i<selectedIdList.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject clientObject = new JSONObject();
                clientObject.put("id", selectedIdList.get(i));
                clientArray.put(clientObject);

            }
        }



    public class ClientListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ClientListData> clientListData;
    public JSONArray clientArray = new JSONArray();
    OnClickListener onClickListener;
    public ClientListAdapter(List<ClientListData> clientListData, Context context,OnClickListener onclick) {
        super();

        this.clientListData = clientListData;
        this.context = context;
onClickListener=onclick;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ClientListData clientListDataModel = clientListData.get(position);
        holder.clientList.setText(clientListDataModel.getClientName());

        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(clientListDataModel.isSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
 holder.clientList.setTag(position);
        holder.clientList.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return clientListData == null ? 0:clientListData.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView clientList;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            clientList = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_client_list);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will have a look at it as well

Comment: The solution you provided is impressive but the the Button to send the values is in my Activity Class, right below the RecyclerView element in the layout file, so I created an interface to transfer the clientArray and implemented the interface in my Activity Class. Now, I don't know how do I get the actual array in Activity Class

Comment: write your clicklistener on activity/fragment not in adapter just pass clicklistener reference to adapter and take call back in activity

Comment: My click listener is in the Activity itself and I am overriding the method in the Activity after implementing the interface. Do you want me to update the code

Comment: I posted a new question based on this issue

Comment: check this ans is usefully for you or not

Comment: Sure, let me give a try

Comment: sorry ,wait  add previously Click listener code mistakenly i am added your clickListener code will update you

Comment: Sure, let me give a try

Comment: I tried your method and I solved the issue, Thank you for your help and patince